# Memory Game some questions

Tags: java, arrays, jbutton

I am trying to create memory game with an images. The user has to match the pictures.

I have two issues right now:

1. I don't understand how do I hide the pictures in the beginning (instead of having them visible as of now)
2. I am also trying to figure out how do I compare the pictures.

Here is the code,

Thank you.

```
package lib;

import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class MemoryGame extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private Timer tmrTime;
    private int seconds = 0;

    private JPanel panel;
    private JLabel lblTimer;

    private JButton btnStart;
    private int p, q, c, count = 0;
    private int[][] check = new int[4][4];

    private static ImageIcon one = new ImageIcon("a.png"), two = new ImageIcon(
            "b.png"), three = new ImageIcon("c.png"), four = new ImageIcon(
            "d.png"), five = new ImageIcon("e.png"), six = new ImageIcon(
            "f.png"), seven = new ImageIcon("g.png"), eight = new ImageIcon(
            "h.png");

    private static ImageIcon[] a = { one, two, three, four, five, six, seven,
            eight };
    private static JButton[][] b = new JButton[4][4];

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new MemoryGame();
    }

    public MemoryGame() {

        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            c = 0;
            do {
                p = (int) (Math.random() * 4);
                q = (int) (Math.random() * 4);
                if (check[p][q] == 0) {
                    c++;
                    check[p][q]++;
                    b[p][q] = new JButton(a[i]);
                    b[p][q].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150, 100));


                    b[p][q].setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
                    b[p][q].setMargin(new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0));
                    //b[p][q].setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
                    b[p][q].setContentAreaFilled(false);
                    b[p][q].addActionListener(this);


                }
            } while (c != 2);
        }

        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 20, 20));

        JLabel lblTitle = new JLabel("MEMORY GAME");
        lblTitle.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(700, 30));
        lblTitle.setFont(new Font("Britannic Bold", Font.BOLD, 28));
        lblTitle.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        panel.add(lblTitle);



        JLabel lblTime = new JLabel("ELAPSED TIME:");
        lblTime.setFont(new Font("Britannic Bold", Font.BOLD, 18));

        lblTimer = new JLabel();
        lblTimer.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 20));
        lblTimer.setFont(new Font("Britannic Bold", Font.BOLD, 18));
        lblTimer.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);

        btnStart = new JButton("START");
        btnStart.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(660, 30));
        btnStart.setFocusable(false);
        btnStart.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
        btnStart.addActionListener(this);



        for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < b[i].length; j++) {
                panel.add(b[i][j]);
            }
        }

        panel.add(btnStart);
        panel.add(lblTime);
        panel.add(lblTimer);

        setContentPane(panel);
        setSize(800, 720);
        setTitle("Memory Game");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        seconds++;
        int minutes = seconds / 60;
        int sec = seconds % 60;


        if (sec < 10) {
            lblTimer.setText("" + minutes + ":0" + sec);
        } else if (seconds > 9) {
            lblTimer.setText("" + minutes + ":" + sec);
        }

        if (e.getSource() == btnStart && count == 0) {
            btnStart.setText("EXIT");
            for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < b[i].length; j++) {

                    //b[i][j].setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
                    b[i][j].setOpaque(false);
                    b[i][j].setContentAreaFilled(false);
                    b[i][j].setBorderPainted(false);


                }
            }

            count++;

            tmrTime = new Timer(1000, this);
            tmrTime.start();


        } else if (e.getSource() == btnStart && count > 0) {
            int option = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,
                    "Are you sure you want to exit ?", "Memory Game",
                    JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
            if (option == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        } else   { 


            if (e.getSource() == b[p][q]) { 
                b[p][q].getSource();
            } 
        }



    }
}
```

Comment: And where is the problem? If the assignment is simply a bit too difficult for you at this point (which is really understandable -- we have all been there), try practising with easier programs, and gradually build your level. We're not here to make your assignments for you, sadly.

Comment: Well I am not asking for a solution(that is not why I am here),  but simple link to a similar example can help me.

Comment: 1. For this you can intially set the icon for all your buttons to some blank or placeholder image and once the start button is clicked, you can reinitialize your buttons to appropriate images. 2. Use a Map as explained by ShaZiv

Answer (score 0):

I think you should map between photos and some unique id. i.e. Each pic would be represented by a uid and when you want to display the pic use map[uid] and to compare pics simply compare the uids.